# Export DataTable to CSV File with "|" Delimiter

Tags: c#, asp.net, csv, datatable, export

I am building an ASP.NET C# project that has a functionality to export DataTables to CSV files with a `|` delimiter for each cell. I want it to look like this:

`100001|06/19/1861|Jose|Rizal|Filipino|Calamba, Laguna|
100002|08/30/1850|Marcelo|Del Pilar|Filipino||
100003||||||`

As you can see, each 'cell' is delimited by `|`. Furthermore, null cells should also have the delimiter. All rows should have the same number of `|` delimiter.

So far I have this code:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
DataTable dtFile1 = file1BLO.SelectAllFile1();
foreach (DataRow dr in dtFile1.Rows)
{
      //build text file
}
```

Comment: @GrantWinney Edited. It's not much.

Comment: This is not CSV.  CSV is "COMMA" 'S'eperated 'V'alues.  You are separating with '|'.

Comment: @jdweng I know what CSV is. This is CSV, but I have a different implementation of it by using `|` instead.

Comment: Technically what you have is a delimited file (not CSV) with '|' as the separator.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); 

string[] columnNames = dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().
                              Select(column => column.ColumnName).
                              ToArray();
sb.AppendLine(string.Join("|", columnNames));

foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    string[] fields = row.ItemArray.Select(field => field.ToString()).
                                ToArray();
    sb.AppendLine(string.Join("|", fields));
}

File.WriteAllText("test.csv", sb.ToString());
```

Comment: This works, but it doesn't add a delimiter at the end of the row.

Comment: I got this to work by modifying this line: `sb.AppendLine(string.Join("|", fields) + "|");`

Answer (score 1):

I used to use this [solution](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/415732/Reading-and-Writing-CSV-Files-in-Csharp).

I exported 200k records and it took about 20 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;

using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication33
{
    class Program
    {
        const stating FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.txt";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataTable dtFile1 = new DataTable();
            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(FILENAME);

            foreach (DataRow row in dtFile1.AsEnumerable())
            {
                writer.WriteLine(string.Join("|", row.ItemArray.Select(x => x.ToString())) + "|");
            }

        }

    }
}
```